# Unable to run Jquery from local folder

Tags: jquery, ftp, directory, local

Hi I am new to web development. I need to work with **JQuery**. Even I have tried one jquery successfully **but only after copying file to my online ftp folder**. I am totally failed to run it from my local folder. Please explain it, how **can I test some new scripts without** having an additional excercise of **copying file to ftp folder**. Thanks in advance!

The Script I used (infect just copied from [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_lib_google) 
still this script only runs from ftp folder and **I am unable to run it from my local folder.** You can see there is not any local or fixed path that should be available from one place but not from another. The script is as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Now is not it possible to run this code from a folder on my on hard drive?

Comment: You should add some of your code. For example the main html file... Does your browser console returns any error? You may be wrong in one of your path...

Comment: Can you include some more info please? the html your using to include the js files and the location of the files on your machine would be useful.

Comment: the jquery src is wrong, it should be `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Include in your head tag:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Like:

```
<head>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

Include `head` tag

```
<html>
<head>
      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this.

```
<head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">/script>
</head>
<body>
<p></P><input type=button value="Click me" id="btn1"/>

  <script>

  $('#btn1').click(function()
  {
      $('p').html("Hello World!");
  });

  </script>
</body>
```